# MS sql insert random number set to the parameter using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do i make the parameter code_gen, give and insert a random value.

```
 @DATE_CREATED datetime = null,
 @STATUS varchar(10) = 'Open',
 @CODE_GEN as ('TN'+ SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),3))+'-'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),5)

as
set nocount on
INSERT INTO MEDREC_CODEGEN (Status,DATE_CREATED,CODE_GEN)
values (@STATUS, COALESCE(@DATE_CREATED,GETDATE()), @CODE_GEN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use expressions as default values on a stored procedure declaration. You can, however, use them with the `SET` statement once inside your code.

This fails:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @Parameter INT = (100 + 50) -- Incorrect syntax near '('.
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN @Parameter

END
```

This works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @Parameter INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET @Parameter = 100 + 50

    RETURN @Parameter

END
```

For your case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure
    @DATE_CREATED datetime = null,
    @STATUS varchar(10) = 'Open',
    @CODE_GEN VARCHAR(200) = NULL
as
BEGIN

    set nocount on

    IF @CODE_GEN IS NULL
        SET @CODE_GEN = ('TN'+ SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),3))+'-'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),5)

    INSERT INTO MEDREC_CODEGEN (Status,DATE_CREATED,CODE_GEN)
    values (@STATUS, COALESCE(@DATE_CREATED,GETDATE()), @CODE_GEN)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server accepts only [literals as parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) defaults.

> default
>
> A default value for a parameter. If a default value is defined
> for a parameter, the procedure can be executed without specifying a
> value for that parameter. The default value must be a **constant** or it
> can be **NULL**..

Change it into a SET statement inline, perhaps with an ISNULL if you set the default to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be help

```
DECLARE @DATE_CREATED AS DATETIME = NULL

 DECLARE @STATUS AS  varchar(10) = 'Open'

 DECLARE  @CODE_GEN as varchar(10) = NULL
 SET @CODE_GEN = ('TN'+ (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),3))+'-
                 '+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),5))

set nocount on
        INSERT INTO MEDREC_CODEGEN (Status,DATE_CREATED,CODE_GEN)
        values (@STATUS, COALESCE(@DATE_CREATED,GETDATE()), @CODE_GEN)
```

Here what I did

```
create table #Temp
(
    Status Varchar(50), 
    DATE_CREATED Varchar(50), 
    CODE_GEN Varchar(50)
)
DECLARE @DATE_CREATED AS DATETIME = NULL

 DECLARE @STATUS AS  varchar(10) = 'Open'

 DECLARE  @CODE_GEN as varchar(10) = NULL
 SET @CODE_GEN = ('TN'+ (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),3))+'-
                 '+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(100), NEWID()),5))

set nocount on
        INSERT INTO #Temp (Status,DATE_CREATED,CODE_GEN)
        values (@STATUS, COALESCE(@DATE_CREATED,GETDATE()), @CODE_GEN)


Select * FROM #Temp
```

Result :

```
Status  DATE_CREATED         CODE_GEN
Open    Apr  4 2018 12:23PM  TN437-
```

Comment: it says "Must declare the scalar variable "@CODE_GEN""

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort